# Firefox is very slow when a lot of tabs are opened

Tags: firefox, evernote

Firefox (version 49) is very slow when it has opened a lot of tabs. Sometimes, it may become unresponsive when I switch to a new tab.

Updated: 
The latest evernote web clipper(6.10.2.0) still makes Firefox very slow even when Firefox's multiprocess is enabled. The web clipper 6.2.0 is still the fastest one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the Firefox extensions. After I disabled evernote clipper, Firefox becomes lighting-fast again. I have tried several clipper versions, and [evernote clipper 6.2.0](https://addons.mozilla.org/zh-TW/firefox/addon/evernote-web-clipper/versions/?page=1#version-6.2.0) is the most stable one. It doesn't causes any slowdowns. The newer versions (6.10 and 6.9) are slow like hell.

Comment: You could also try the latest stable Firefox (50.1.0). It is much faster than 49.

Comment: Check your extensions with Mozilla's *Add-on Compatibility Reporter*. If any extension is not E10s compliant, Firefox reverts from multi-process to single-process functionality.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thanks, it's really helpful. Evernote clipper doesn't support multi-process. I wish Evernote could fix it in the future.